# in Linq replace null to empty

Tags: c#, api, linq, entity-framework-migrations

```
var ch = _context.xxtu_nintex_emp_data_v
         .Where(o => o.LOGIN_USER_NAME ==userId.ToUpper())
         .Select(emp => new
         { OTHERMOBILENO = emp.OTHERMOBILENO ?? "" })
         .ToList().SingleOrDefault();
```

the result is

[image]

when use toList() I get what I want but it is so slow

```
var ch = _context.xxtu_nintex_emp_data_v.ToList()
         .Where(o => o.LOGIN_USER_NAME ==userId.ToUpper())
         .Select(emp => new
         { OTHERMOBILENO = emp.OTHERMOBILENO ?? "" })
         .ToList().SingleOrDefault();
```

the result is

[image]

> I use code first approach api and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Don't use `ToList` before you add the `Where` filter, that will cause the entire table to be loaded into your applications memory and filtered there.

Comment: Also, why do you care if it is null or empty string?

Comment: Also don't use the second `ToList`. `SingleOrDefault` would be enough.

Comment: OTHERMOBILENO =( emp == null) ? "" : emp.OTHERMOBILENO

Comment: I think until you get the response from database, the value is dbnull.value not null

Comment: @DavidG because backend team work with empty "" value and when I use null should backend team change all code to work with null.

Comment: @PeterCsala I want the result only  `{......}` not `[ {  .....  } ]` it is work olny this `. SingleOrDefault`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some things you could try

1. Call `ToList` after the condition, to only fetch a subset of data from the Database

   ```
    var ch = _context.xxtu_nintex_emp_data_v
         .Where(o => o.LOGIN_USER_NAME == userId.ToUpper())
         .ToList() //<-- here
         .Select(emp => new
         { OTHERMOBILENO = emp.OTHERMOBILENO ?? "" })
         .ToList().SingleOrDefault();
   ```
2. Move the `Select` after the Last `ToList` call

   ```
    var ch = _context.xxtu_nintex_emp_data_v
         .Where(o => o.LOGIN_USER_NAME == userId.ToUpper())
         //<-- re-arrange ToList/Select
         .ToList()
         .Select(emp => new { OTHERMOBILENO = emp.OTHERMOBILENO ?? "" }) 
         //<-- 
         .SingleOrDefault();
   ```
3. Re-arrange it a bit more

   ```
    var emp = _context.xxtu_nintex_emp_data_v
         .Where(o => o.LOGIN_USER_NAME == userId.ToUpper())
         .SingleOrDefault();

    var ch = new { OTHERMOBILENO = emp?.OTHERMOBILENO ?? "" };
   ```

Comment: it is work ToList after the condition, Can u explain more details?

Comment: @sp4_4 - The `ToList()` after the condition, is basically the same as you showed, and claimed it works for your scenario, the only difference is that the condition will be evaluated on the server (database) - `ToList()` forces `EntityFramework` to evaluate the `LINQ` and parse everything before to `SQL` and send it to the server, so calling the `ToList()` will parse an sql expression with the condition included and only those rows meeting the condition will need to moved from server to client